# Getting timeout on my OnePlus 5T while running Appium

Tags: java, appium

I am using Appium version 1.15.0 and while running my Appium app automation suite on my OnePlus 5T, I am getting error : An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after 5441 ms. Timing out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide your capabilities